# According to the Catholic Church, do guardian angels graduate?

Tags: catholicism, angels, guardian-angels

I received two conflicting reports from two women whose catholicity I highly respect, but whose sources are circumspect, or at the very least circumlocutory.

- One says that if and when we get to heaven, our guardian angel gets
  promoted up the ranks.
- The other says that if and when we get to heaven, our guardian angel
  stays with us, and remains our guardian angel in heaven.

I'm not an expert, nor do I know if these things can be known. However, I do know a contradiction when I see one. Which is right? Do our angels graduate, or do they remain with us in Eternity?

Catholic answers only, please - no Sylvia Browne.

Comment: If the two women are highly recognizable, can you post their names. Also what does she mean by higher ranks? Promoted to higher in [Nine orders of angels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_angelic_hierarchy)? (Because that would be impossible because of their nature) I have heard that they help the soul even in Purgatory, by reminding their relatives down here to pray for them. When a soul enters heaven I personally do not think they need the help of Guardian angles anymore.

Comment: One is my wife, the other is the DRE at my parish. And yeah, rise up the ranks = ascend the 7 choirs.

Comment: I hope you meant 9 choirs/orders/hierarchy, or is 7 choirs a completely separate distinction?

Comment: @JayarathinaMadharasan Nope, no distinction just ignorance.  I'm glad there's 9 of something, I usually miss that number in my Catechism class's countdown: 1 God, 2 Natures, 3 Persons, 4 Gospels, 5 Precepts of the Church, 6 days of creation, 7 sacraments, 8 beatitudes, 9 choirs of angels, 10 commandments, 11 good apostles, 12 stars in Mary's crown.

Comment: @PeterTurner If we count Paul as an apostle, [which we should](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+9&version=NIV), then there were 12 good apostles.

Comment: Where in the bible does it say about Angels. Pure speculation.

Comment: [Matthew 18:10](http://www.usccb.org/bible/matthew/18:10)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think angels can be promoted from one order to another within the 9 orders. Simply because they are in that specific order by their very nature. Just like a dog can't be a cat or a Rose can never be Lilly.

Also note that they are helping us to save our souls because God wanted them to do that, not to get "promotion" in their Job. After the end of their duty, the angelic orders will continue to exist, but their offices will not be altogether the same as they now are, for they will then no longer need to help human beings in the process of saving their souls.

> The distinction of grades among the angels ... will ever remain in the angels; for these **differences of natures cannot be taken from them** unless they themselves be corrupted. The difference of glory will also ever remain in them according to the difference of preceding merit. As to the execution of the angelic offices ... **It will cease accordingly as their offices are directed towards leading others to their end;** but it will remain, accordingly as it agrees with the attainment of the end.  <sup>[Summa Theologica 1:108:7](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/1108.htm#article7)</sup>

As said above by St. Thomas Aquinas the only purpose of Guardian angel is to save our souls, their function towards us cease to exist after we enter heaven or hell. (Since we are in the process of being cleansed, our angels do continue to pray for us and urge saints and humans to pray for us when we are in purgatory)

Also remember:

- Our Guardian Angels are not our servants but our masters.<sup>[src](http://taylormarshall.com/2011/06/you-are-not-allowed-to-name-your.html)</sup>
- In heaven we will have God and so we will lack nothing. He will be our only need and our provider of our need, we will not need an angel's help anymore.